# How to correctly localize fields in forms?

Tags: django, localization

I use Django 3.0.4 and Crispy Forms 1.9.0

I have the following model:

```
class App(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, db_index=True, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Platform'))
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=512, unique=True, verbose_name=_('Package name'))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True, verbose_name=_('Created Date'))
```

Form:

```
class CreateAppForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = App
        fields = ('name', 'platform', 'package_name',)
        localized_fields = '__all__' # I've tried to enumerate fields as tuple
        # labels = { # I've tried to uncomment it
        #     'name': _('Name'),
        #     'platform': _('Platform'),
        #     'package_name': _('Package name'),
        # }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['platform'].queryset = Platform.objects.filter(is_enabled=True)
```

And template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}{% trans "Create application" %}{% endblock %}
{% block page_title %}{% trans "Create application" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                <div class="card-header py-3">
                    <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">{% trans "Create application" %}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form class="form" action="{% url 'apps:create' %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}

                        {{ form|crispy }}

                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> {% trans "Create" %}</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

All strings in .po files are localized and compiled (and work everywhere but in forms).

The form renders correctly, but the fields' labels are not localized:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: The underscore `_` used in the model. Can you also show where is it coming from?

Comment: @AKS it's `from django.utils.translation import gettext as _`

Comment: Django documentation recommends to use [`gettext_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#model-fields-and-relationships-verbose-name-and-help-text-option-values) for the verbose names of model fields. Could you try that instead?

Comment: @AKS that worked! Please, post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django documentation recommends to use [`gettext_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#model-fields-and-relationships-verbose-name-and-help-text-option-values) for the verbose names of model fields.

> This is essential when calls to these functions are located in code paths that are executed at module load time.
>
> This is something that can easily happen when defining models, forms and model forms, because Django implements these such that their fields are actually class-level attributes. For that reason, make sure to use lazy translations in the following cases:
>
> **Model fields and relationships `verbose_name` and `help_text` option values**